# How to use injected service in listener?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to use injected service in listener? In ngOnInit ofcourse it works. But i cant use it in listener.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../shared/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'mmm-face-id',
  templateUrl: './face-id.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./face-id.component.css']
})
export class FaceIdComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) { } // <- Service

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.authService); // <- Everything is fine

    window.addEventListener("message", this.receiveMessage, false);
  }

  receiveMessage(event) {
    console.log(this.authService); // <- Not working. AuthService is null.

    // ...
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you still get the error if you change `public authService` to `private authService` in the constructor?

Comment: yes. it is still undefined

Comment: What are you seeing in the console onInit?

Comment: Looks like a scoping issue. Can you try this.receiveMessage.bind(this) ?

Comment: Try setting the handler with an arrow function: `window.addEventListener("message", (e) => { this.receiveMessage(e); }, false);`., or define the callback as an arrow function: `receiveMessage = (event) => { ... }`. Or use `this.receiveMessage.bind(this)` as suggested by @MikeOne.